Error in merging adapter with model in autotrain
I am trying to use autotrain from Hugging Face to fine tune some models. Since I don't have big computing resources, I tried to fine tune model EleutherAI/pythia-14m and this dataset. But I recieved this message:
Failed to merge adapter weights: Error(s) in loading state_dict for PeftModelForCausalLM:
    size mismatch for base_model.model.gpt_neox.embed_in.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([50280, 128]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([50277, 128]).
    size mismatch for base_model.model.embed_out.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([50280, 128]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([50277, 128]).

This error occured when I started this script, that is just terminal command, written in Jupiter.
!autotrain llm \
    --train \
    --model "EleutherAI/pythia-14m" \
    --project-name "my-llm" \
    --data-path data/ \
    --text-column text \
    --batch-size "4" \
    --lr "2e-5" \
    --epochs "3" \
    --block-size "1024" \
    --warmup-ratio "0.03" \
    --lora-r "16" \
    --lora-alpha "32" \
    --lora-dropout "0.05" \
    --weight-decay "0." \
    --gradient-accumulation "4" \
    --logging-steps "10" \
    --use-peft \
    --merge-adapter \

Also, the same problem showed, when I tried to autotrain in Hugging Face space.
I am not experienced in ml, so I can't imagine, what can cause this problem.
